# How can I Roundoff in SQL with a sum function

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sum, rounding

In My SQL Code I am trying to round the value to 2 decimal point with sum

```
select ((SUM(Round((CAST(PE.GstTotal as float) * PE.Quantity) / 2 ),2))) FROM [dbo].[PharmacyEntry] PE
```

But I am getting an error. Could someone correct me on this.
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKLKe.png)

Comment: FYI: SQL Server 2008 ran entirely out of support ~30 months ago. It is *long* past time you start on your upgrade path by now.

Comment: Also, [please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: The error is telling you the problem though, `SUM` does only accept 1 parameter and you are providing 2. Check your parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

It's sometimes helpful to vertically align all your parenthesis pairs to see where you've got one wrong:

```
    select 
    (
      (
        SUM
        (
          Round
          (
            (
              CAST
                (
                   PE.GstTotal as float
                ) 
                * 
                PE.Quantity
            ) 
            /
            2 
          ),
          2
        )
      )
    ) 

FROM [dbo].[PharmacyEntry] PE
```

Answer (score 1):

You're providing `2` as a second parameter to `sum` instead of `round`. Try this:

```
select SUM(Round((CAST(PE.GstTotal as float) * PE.Quantity) / 2 , 2)) 
FROM [dbo].[PharmacyEntry] PE
```